# How do I figure out the xpath of an element in perl?

Tags: xml, perl, xpath

I'm trying to figure out if there's a good way of determining the xpath of an XML node.

At the moment, I'm doing this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->parse( \*DATA );
print $twig ->get_xpath( '/root/fish/carrot[@colour="orange"]/pie', 0 )->text,
    "\n";

foreach my $node ( $twig->get_xpath('//*') ) {
    my @path_tags;
    my @path_with_att;
    my $cursor = $node;
    while ($cursor) {
        unshift( @path_tags, $cursor->tag );

        my $att_path = "";
        if ( $cursor->atts ) {
            $att_path = join( "",
                map { "[@" . $_ . "=\"" . $cursor->att($_) . "\"]" }
                    keys %{ $cursor->atts } );
        }
        unshift( @path_with_att, $cursor->tag . $att_path );
        $cursor = $cursor->parent;
    }

    print join( "/", @path_tags ), "\n";

    my $xpath_with_atts = "/" . join( "/", @path_with_att );
    print $xpath_with_atts, "\n";
    print "Found:", $twig->get_xpath( $xpath_with_atts, 0 )->tag, "\n";
}

__DATA__
<root>
   <fish skin="scaly" home="pond">
      <carrot colour="orange">
          <pie>This value</pie>
      </carrot>
   </fish>
</root>
```

Which I'm traversing the structure (using a wildcard xpath, perhaps slightly ironically - but the point is I'd like to be able to do this within e.g. a twig handler).

And then recursively traversing *up* the tree to figure out two variants of the `xpath` of the current node (with and without elements). This is of course recognising that an xpath is by no means necessarily unique, so there may well be duplicate (that last 'found' is purely a validation step).

But this is because I couldn't find a what-is-my-xpath method in either of the two XML libraries I tend to favour (`XML::Twig` and `XML::LibXML`).

So my question is - is there actually an inbuilt mechanism in an XML library I can (and should) use? If there isn't, is there actually some reason why not?

I mean, my above samples work, but I'm wondering if there's some nuance whereby this approach (or something similar) isn't viable for the whole range of the XML spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML::LibXML has `$node->nodePath()`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $xml = <<'__EOI__';
<root>
<fish>
<carrot colour="purple"><pie/></carrot>
<carrot colour="orange"><pie/></carrot>
<carrot colour="blue"><pie/></carrot>
</fish>
</root>
__EOI__

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_string($xml);
say $_->nodePath()
   for $doc->findnodes("//pie");
```

Output:

```
/root/fish/carrot[1]/pie
/root/fish/carrot[2]/pie
/root/fish/carrot[3]/pie
```

It uses position rather than attributes to identify ambiguities since attributes may not uniquely identify an element.

Note that the path may produce multiple results if used in another document due to lack of `[1]` on nodes of which there were only one in the original document.

As to why XML::Twig doesn't have one, this isn't a very useful feature. If you're just working with one document, you already have a reference to the node. If you want to craft a path that will work for more than one document, it's just not possible for the module to know what the proper path should be. For example, which of the following is correct?

```
/a/b
/a/b[1]
/a/b[@id="123"]
/a/b[@default="1"]
/a/b[@id="123" && @default="1"]
```